# Can I make a file always load from server?

Tags: css

In my website I have changed css of a page and these changes are not reflecting instantly when I open that page in browser. It showing old css styles because browser has a saved copy of my css file and it does not reflecting the new changes.

The new changes are loading in the page when I load the page by pressing (CTRL+F5) then the changes I have done are reflected in the page. So can I make css file which always loaded from server and the changes done that page can reflect immediately on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your head tag

```
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0">
```

Comment: Expires is deprecated, HTTP1.1 Cache-Control is supported by effectively all browsers, and takes precedence over expires.

Comment: Ah. Good to know. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Setting the http header for Cache Control

If you don't have access to the low level http headers, you can use a [http equiv](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_meta_http_equiv.asp) tag. Example:

```html
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, must-revalidate">
```

Source: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching#cache-control

Comment: Thanks @ManmeetGill